# PHPUnit can not run test

Tags: php, selenium

When executing the test, there is such an error:

`This test did not perform any assertions
OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!`

PHPUnit 6.2.2, PHP 7.0, Selenium 3.4.0

```
protected $url = "https://click.alfabank.ru";
public function testSearch()
{
    $this->webDriver->get($this->url);
    sleep(20);
    $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::name('username'))->sendKeys('test');
}
```

Help in solving this problem!

Comment: you are not asserting anything (performing any tests)

Comment: assign line 3 to a variable, say `$urlCheck`, then do `$this->assertEquals($url, $urlCheck);`

Comment: The test runs. You're just not asserting anything. I suggest you take a read of the Phpunit manual, it has an introduction on how to write tests.